# Start animation when player enters specific distance

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to start an animation when my player enters a specific distance to an object, but my animation isn't starting. Any suggestion as to why it isn't starting?

Here is the code that I have so far:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
public class MoveTo : MonoBehaviour {
    public Transform Player;
    public Transform goal;
    public Animator ani;
    public Animator ani2;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {
        ani.Stop (); // this stop function is working accurate
        ani2.Stop ();
    }
    void Update()
    {
        float dist = Vector3.Distance (Player.position, transform.position);
        if (dist < 5)
        {
            ani.Play("Horse_Walk");// this is not working (Horse_Walk) is a state name
            ani2.Play("Horse_Run");
            pstart();
        }
    }
    void pstart(){
        NavMeshAgent agent=GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
        agent.destination = goal.position;
    }
}
```

Comment: when you say it s not working do you mean that the animation doesnt start? you can take a look at the state machine of the animator of your object while you think the anim should start it will maybe give you a lead

Comment: maybe it is working but right away fading to another animation in your state machine so you dont see it?

Comment: Yes, its not working means animation doesn't start.... @HaimBendanan

Comment: Maybe it's because you are calling the Play function lots of time per second? You are in the Update function. Once your boolean condition is reached (dist < 5) you start calling play multiple times. You should add a flag or monitor the state of your object if thats the case.

Comment: this is on the horse? make use of a (spherical) trigger and its callbacks.

Comment: simply use a trigger collider here, Farhan.  absolutely do not try to do any calculations yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be several reason including (1) wrong string  (2) string name not matched and finally which seems more appropriate reason is that you playing animation again. you should need be call it with bool

```
    bool isPlayAnim =true;
        void Update()
            {
                float dist = Vector3.Distance (Player.position, transform.position);
                if (dist < 5 && isPlayAnim)
                {
                    isPlayAnim = false;//again true it on you specfic event
                    ani.Play("Horse_Walk");// this is not working (Horse_Walk) is a state name
                    ani2.Play("Horse_Run");
                    pstart();
                }
            }
```

isPlayAnim bool you can make and use to play animation only one time and again true it in specific event.

**Or**

Alternatively you need to use collider and its event to run this update code. I guess it is best way to do this job .